# Count # of checkboxes as part of a function within Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, count

I am trying to integrate a count of checkboxes into the following MailApp.sendEmail function to display the number of checkboxes against a certain quota. The checkboxes to be counted are in Column A. I would appreciate any guidance to count the checkboxes within the MailApp.sendEmail function or as a separate function but retrievable. I find this challenging in apps script.

```
var quotaLeft = getRemainingDailyQuota();
Logger.log(quotaLeft);

if(countOfCheckboxes > quotaLeft){
Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " and you're trying to send " + countOfCheckboxes + " emails.       Emails were not sent.);
}
```

This is the stand-alone function to count checkboxes but is there a way to do it within the above function?

```
function countOfCheckboxes(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  var range = sheet.getRange("a:a");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var count = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === true) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
//Logger.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the snippets that you provided like this:

```
function countOfCheckboxes() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
  var range = sheet.getRange("a:a");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var quotaLeft = getRemainingDailyQuota();
  var count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === true) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  if (count > quotaLeft) {
    Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " and you're trying to send " + count + " emails. Emails were not sent.");
    return;
  }
  var emailAddress = "email@example.com";
  var subject = "Your Subject";
  var body = "Your Body";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body);
}
```

I'm assuming that `getRemainingDailyQuota()` is already working because you did not include its snippet in the question. I just put a random number in for testing.

This is what I get when the quota is not enough:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvDfk.png]

This is what I get when the email is sent:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tclbl.jpg]

Comment: Thank you very much, Stack! This is solved.

Regarding the `getRemainingDailyQuota()`, I had left out MailApp. With it, it works as intended.